# Plotting each Cluster value percentage individually

Tags: python, pandas

So I have been working on this problem for a bit and seem to be stuck..so I am asking for some guidance here.

This is my code

```
from clusteval import clusteval
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import pandas as pd
X, labels = make_blobs(n_samples=50, centers=2, n_features=5, cluster_std=1)
X = abs(X)
X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['Feature_1','Feature_2','Feature_3','Feature_4','Feature_5'])
ce = clusteval('kmeans', metric='euclidean', linkage='complete')
results = ce.fit(X)
X['Cluster_labels'] = results['labx']
X.groupby('Cluster_labels').Feature_1.value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind='bar')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This produces this image:
[image: percentage of each value within the clusters]

This image is really close to what I want but notice that both clusters show up in the same graph. I would like to produce the same graph represents only one cluster. essentially for every cluster I have I want a graph like this. So if I had 10 clusters, I would have 10 graphs that showed the percentage of each value within that cluster and that cluster only.

Any guidance or help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Each bar in the current plot ends up being exactly the same height. Is that intended? This happens because each of the 50 values of `Feature_1` is distinct (each cluster has 25 distinct values of `Feature_1`), so calling `value_counts(normalize=True)` simply returns a normalized count of 1/25 = 0.04 for each value, which doesn't seem helpful. The actual feature values show up in the x tick labels. Would you prefer to show the feature values in the plot?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! So for this example I ended up using make_blobs() to come up with the data because I cannot use my actual data. So the percentage for each values across the cluster is the same. I dont want to plot the value, I want to plot the percentage, I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two alternative plots. Both would benefit from visual refinement (label all axes, clean up underscores, pick nicer font sizes, etc.) but hopefully are useful starting points.

Using pandas:

```
axes = X.hist('Feature_1', by='Cluster_labels')
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_title('Cluster_labels = ' + ax.get_title())
```

[image: pandas plot of Feature 1 distribution by cluster label]

Using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.displot(X, 
            x='Feature_1', 
            col='Cluster_labels', 
            binwidth=0.5)
```

[image: seaborn plot of Feature 1 distribution by cluster label]

Comment: Hey first off thank you so much for taking the time to answer. Your solution is helpful in presenting my data in a different way. What I believe you are doing is showing the count of each value within the cluster right? Also is the binwidth able to be just a bin of 1 element? Because I need to see the count of each value I have.